# How to replace an unfiltered Search API results view with custom text?

Tags: views, search

**Setting:** using the `search_api_views` module, I have created a view with an exposed fulltext search filter. In addition, I have lots of facets for the corresponding search index in a separate block (via the `search_api_facetapi` module). Searching and filtering works well.

**Question:** When no facet item is selected and no fulltext search is used, then all indexed nodes are shown in the view as search results. How can I replace this full nodes list with a custom text (e.g., “Enter a search term or select a facet item to filter our products.”)? In other words: how can I hide the results list if and only if no search filter (facet or fulltext) is applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s how I solved this:

First I implemented `hook_views_post_build`. Note, that I could have probably used most other [views processing hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7), too, as I’m only adding custom build information.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_build().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_post_build(&$view) {

  // If there is no explicit search being done, then we show a message instead
  // of all search results. We still have to run the search under the hood so
  // that we have correct search facets available. Therefore we could have also
  // used most other views processing hooks here.
  if ($view->name === 'MY_VIEW_NAME' && empty($view->exposed_input['f'])
       && empty($view->exposed_input['search'])) {
    $view->build_info['MY_MODULE_show_message'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Then I added my custom message to an overridden `views-view.tpl.php` using the previously defined build info variable:

```php
<!-- … views template header here … -->
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

  <?php if (isset($view->build_info['MY_MODULE_show_message'])): ?>
    <h2>My Custom Message</h2>
    <p>Enter a search term or select a facet item to filter our products.</p>
  <?php else: ?>
    <!-- … normal views content here … -->
  <?php endif; ?>

</div><?php /* class view */ ?>
```